# Group lines with Numeric and AlphaNumeric (LINQ)

Tags: linq, numeric, alphanumeric, linq-group

I have a dataset with a column having Numeric and AlphaNumeric Order Nos. Data is being grouped up with different columns which result in merging rows together. Now I want to group lines based on Numeric and AlphaNumeric Order Nos as well, for that purpose I have to evaluate string (data) whether it is Numeric or AlphaNumeric. Following is the statement which groups up data together.

```
var groupLinesETAFile = (from g in strLinesETAFile
                         group g by new
                         {
                             g.PONo,
                             g.POLineNo,
                             g.POSubLineNo,
                             g.AllocatedPartNo
                         } into grouped
                         select new
                         {
                             PONo = grouped.Key.PONo,
                             POLineNo = grouped.Key.POLineNo,
                             POSubLineNo = grouped.Key.POSubLineNo,
                             AllocatedPartNo = grouped.Key.AllocatedPartNo,
                             ETAQty = grouped.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.ETAQty))
                         }).ToList();
```

Now I want to add a new column in statement "SupplierOrderNo" which has Numeric and AlphaNumeric Values and want to group on Numeric and AlphaNumeric values as well. How can I achieve this with LINQ?

Comment: And where should this `SupplierOrderNo` come from?

Comment: "SupplierOrderNo" column is already there in dataset but it was not being used, now I have to use it.

Comment: "I did A, now I want to do A again, how do I do this?" Are you sure you did it the first time? If you did, can you explain why the solution does not work for you this time?

Comment: @nvoigt I guess you didn't read the whole question. First, data was not grouped by Numeric and AlphaNumeric data, now I want to group it based on those values as well.

Comment: @user3675273 I know what you want. I simply doubt the fact that you could do the first statement on your own, only to discover grouping by something else is beyond your capabilites. You stated what you *want*. Great. Hire somebody who does it for you. If you want *help doing it*, please show some effort and post your best try and your problem where you are stuck.